# node.js winston logging module - how to put timestamp at start of line instead of end

Tags: javascript, node.js, winston

I have the following code inside a common.js file:

```
var winston = require('winston');

winston.add(winston.transports.File, { 'timestamp':true, name:'log.error', filename: './app_error.log',level:'error', eol:'\n'});
winston.add(winston.transports.File, { 'timestamp':true, name:'log.warn', filename: './app_warn.log',level:'warn', eol:'\n'});
winston.add(winston.transports.File, { 'timestamp':true, name:'log.debug', filename: './app_debug.log',level:'debug', eol:'\n'});
```

The contents of the files look something like this:

> {"level":"info","message":"router.get() attempting dbquery using :10244","timestamp":"2016-10-26T20:51:21.428Z"}
>
> {"level":"info","message":"hash_get() invoked with 10244 callerid","timestamp":"2016-10-26T20:51:21.435Z"}

I'd like to know how I can have the timestamp be the first field in the line, and without the word "timestamp".
something like this:

> {"2016-10-26T20:51:21.428Z", "level":"info","message":"router.get() attempting dbquery using :10244"}

**EDIT 1**

Tried to change my code to look like this:

**common.js**

```
var winston = require('winston');
winston.add(winston.transports.File, {
        'timestamp':function() {
                return moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS");
        },
        name:'log.debug', 
        filename: './app_debug.log',
        level:'debug',
        eol:'\n',
        formatter: function(options) {
                // Return string will be passed to logger.
                return options.timestamp() +' '+ options.level.toUpperCase() +' '+ (undefined !== options.message ? options.message : '') +
                (options.meta && Object.keys(options.meta).length ? '\n\t'+ JSON.stringify(options.meta) : '' );
        }
});
exports.winston = winston;
```

**router**

```
var common = require('./common');
var winston = common.winston; 

 if (debug) { winston.log('info','router.get() query to db returned - ' + data); }
```

But the system is still putting the timestamp at the end.

Comment: You can implement [a custom log format](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#custom-log-format). You do realize that the output you're showing yields invalid JSON?

Comment: You can create a custom format/template with the `formatter` parameter: https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#custom-log-format